# SSRS Data Driven Subscription Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to enable Data Driven Subscriptions but when I select the "On a schedule created for this subscription" the next button is greyed out

[image: as shown in the image]

If I click on finish, I get the following error:

*The value for parameter 'matchData' is not specified. It is either missing from the function call, or it is set to null. (rsMissingParameter) Get Online Help.*

Can someone please help?

Comment: I am pretty sure that Data-Driven subscriptions are supported only by SQL Server Enterprise and Developer editions.  Are you using one of these two editions?

Comment: @DavidTansey I'm pretty sure if you didn't have enterprise the option for DDS is not presented! So I don't think that is the issue! why is the "Next" greyed out? you should be able to specify the schedule.. is your dataset returning the correct parameters? If not, do you have a default for the parameter "matchDate"?

Comment: I'm using Enterprise Edition and there is no parameters that is setup for the report. I'm executing a stored procedure to retrieve the emails that I want to sent emails to using the subscription. The actual subscription works fine, its only the data driven subscription that I'm having issues with as the "To" email might change from time to time and I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: @Karu3103 the error message indicates otherwise - re parameter. are you able to execute the stored procedure without any parameters in management studio? I.E. using the command exec your_stored_procedure_name. How do you decide who to send the email to? That is why you had a dataset for the data driven subscription to determine all of this at run time..

Comment: the following command gives me the result set and in one of the columns it has all email addresses that I need to send emails to: exec <ProcedureName>. I use this in the query to extract the report and also in Step 3 while creating Data Driven Subscription. In Step 4, in the To field, I select the column name which has the email address.

Comment: You definitely have a parameter somewhere called 'matchData', either in the proc or the RDL.  How else did SSRS get it's name?

Comment: There does seem to be an internal MatchData parameter: **MatchData:** Returns XML data specific to the report execution and delivery scheduling process. This is an output parameter. (from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36009/Programmatically-Playing-With-SSRS-Subscriptions ) Not sure why this would be getting an error though. Have you tried starting a new DD Subscription?

Comment: @GandRalph - matchData is not part of the procedure/RDL file.

Comment: @HannoverFist - Yes, tried it multiple times and it throws the same error

Comment: Have you tried deleting the report from the server and re-deploying? MatchData is a field in the Subscriptions table that apparently should be created automatically. For reference, my MatchData field has *<ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><StartDateTime xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer">2019-02-28T02:00:00.000-08:00</StartDateTime></ScheduleDefinition>*